# Get into features of "a" anchors included in a div get by classname

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

I desperately try to find how to change many 'a' anchor features styles within a div, found by their self classname. I think i got you the whole needed code related as below.
I thank you a lot for your time and your help.

HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <a class="boutonmenuprincipal">          <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='logo_sel_lang.png') }}"></a>
    <div class="dropdown_child">
        <a href="" onclick="changeLanguage('fr')">Français  <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='logo_fr.png') }}" class="flags"></a>
        <a href="" onclick="changeLanguage('de')">Deutsch   <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='logo_de.png') }}" class="flags"></a>
        <a href="" onclick="changeLanguage('es')">Español   <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='logo_es.png') }}" class="flags"></a>
        <a href="" onclick="changeLanguage('en')">English   <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='logo_uk.png') }}" class="flags"></a>
        <a href="" onclick="changeLanguage('tk')">Türk      <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='logo_tk.png') }}" class="flags"></a>
        <a href="" onclick="changeLanguage('br')">Brasil    <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='logo_br.png') }}" class="flags"></a>
        <a href="" onclick="changeLanguage('it')">Italiano  <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='logo_it.png') }}" class="flags"></a>
        <a href="" onclick="changeLanguage('ro')">Românesc  <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='logo_ro.png') }}" class="flags"></a>
        <a href="" onclick="changeLanguage('nl')">Nederlands<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='logo_nl.png') }}" class="flags"></a>
        <a href='' onclick='.dropdown:hover disabled'>&times; Close  </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myObj1 = window.document.querySelectorAll('dropdown_child');
myObj1.style.height = '0px';
myObj1.style.color = 'white';
myObj1.style.textDecoration = 'none';
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `querySelector` should include `.` for selecting class.
- If you want to select all 'a' tags in `myObj1`, you have to select `dropdown_child`'s children, not `querySelectorAll('.dropdown_child')`. 
  It'll only select a `.dropdown_chlid` element.

### Solution

```js
const myObj1 = document.querySelector(".dropdown_child").children;
[...myObj1].map((el) => {
  el.style.height = "0px";
  el.style.color = "white";
  el.style.textDecoration = "none";
});
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="boutonmenuprincipal"> <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='logo_sel_lang.png') }}"></a>
  <div class="dropdown_child">
    <a href="" onclick="changeLanguage('fr')">Français <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='logo_fr.png') }}" class="flags"></a>
    <a href="" onclick="changeLanguage('de')">Deutsch <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='logo_de.png') }}" class="flags"></a>
    <a href="" onclick="changeLanguage('es')">Español <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='logo_es.png') }}" class="flags"></a>
    <a href="" onclick="changeLanguage('en')">English <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='logo_uk.png') }}" class="flags"></a>
    <a href="" onclick="changeLanguage('tk')">Türk <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='logo_tk.png') }}" class="flags"></a>
    <a href="" onclick="changeLanguage('br')">Brasil <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='logo_br.png') }}" class="flags"></a>
    <a href="" onclick="changeLanguage('it')">Italiano <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='logo_it.png') }}" class="flags"></a>
    <a href="" onclick="changeLanguage('ro')">Românesc <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='logo_ro.png') }}" class="flags"></a>
    <a href="" onclick="changeLanguage('nl')">Nederlands<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='logo_nl.png') }}" class="flags"></a>
    <a href='' onclick='.dropdown:hover disabled'>&times; Close </a>
  </div>
</div>
```